# How to geocode IP addresses at finer resolution than the city level?

Tags: geocoding

I have tried several Geocoding IP API or tools but found that the Lat/Long output is same for all addresses in the same city, which could not meet my needs. Can anyone suggest a better way to geocode IP addresses at a higher resolution?

Answer (score 8):

IP addresses often don't correspond to the location of a user's machine. For example, right now I'm in Vermont, but two IP geocoding APIs I just checked place me in California. You'll see other people make similar remarks, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/348618/789446) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234102/what-is-the-preferred-method-to-display-local-where-to-buy-information-ip-add).

Aside from the occasional gross inaccuracy, I suggest that IP addresses are also too imprecise to be meaningful below the city level. It's like throwing a beach ball at a dart board: there's no real way to say exactly where the beach ball hit.

Check out [this great answer to a GIS StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/how-does-ip-geocoding-work) for more details on (im)precision of IP geocoding.